# connection between domain and constant "C" in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have some problems with the domain in first-order differential equations. 
 Firstly, while solving the differential equation, I have to assume that $x$ is greater than $0$ (due to a logarithm).  My final solution is $y =$ something$/x + C$.  Well $x + C \neq 0$, so for $x = -C$, I have an asymptote. But I am used to writing it as domain ranges in principals.  So in this case, I believe it will be range $x$ from $(0,-C)$, $(-C,+\infty)$, and $(C < 0)$.  Is this correct?

Comment: Here's an example. y'=(1-ln x)/x^2, when x=1/e then y=-3.  Solution is y=ln x/x +c, x>0. The boundary condition gives -1/(1/e) +c =-3, c=e-3 so y=ln x/x +e-3 The domain is the set of positive reals.